# File handling in C - unexpected output

Tags: c, file-handling

I am trying to figure out the output to the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    int i = 20;
    if ((f = fopen("file.DAT", "wb")) != NULL) {
        fwrite(&i, 4, 1, f);
        fclose(f);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On a `32-bit` system, a `paragraph sign` (decimal `ascii` value `182`) is written to binary file.

**Question**: How to determine which `ascii` value will be written to binary file?

First argument of function `fwrite` is a pointer to array, but array is not defined in the code. How to track which bytes are written to binary file?

Comment: It should (on most platforms I'm aware of) write a space and three NUL bytes. Not a paragraph sign with ASCII value 182.

Comment: `&i` means a pointer to `i`, since `i` is an integer, you correctly write 4 bytes of memory from the address pointed by `i` to `file.DAT`

Comment: @immibis: only for a value `0x20`, not for a *decimal* `20` :) The interpretation of `20` as a character depends on what software you view it with.

Comment: The first argument to [`fwrite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) is just a generic pointer to some data. What that data is doesn't matter.

Comment: @RadLexus Oops, yes, space is ASCII value 32 not 20.

Comment: According to [this Windows ASCII table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa771694(v=bts.10).aspx) the code for ASCII `20` is `DC4`. And it's character *in Windows* is something reassembling a paragraph character. The output is exactly what is expected from your program. I suggest you look at the file with a hex-editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code writes the internal representation of the `int` `i` into the file `file.DAT` opened in binary mode. `&i` is not the address of an array, it is the address of local variable `i`. `fwrite` will write the 4 bytes at that address, which on a 32-bit system make up the integer in question.

On little endian architectures, such as Intel PCs and Macs, file should contain 4 bytes with values:

```
+---------------------------+
| 0x14 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 |
+---------------------------+
```

But on a big endian machine, such as the older Macs, the file contents would be:

```
+---------------------------+
| 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x14 |
+---------------------------+
```

If you print this file to the terminal or load it into an editor, you might see a funny character for the non-ASCII value `0x14` and other marks or none for the null bytes.  This character shows as a paragraph sign, maybe because the editor performs some kind of character set conversion. Use a binary dump utility to see the exact contents of the file.

For more portability, the code should read `fwrite(&i, sizeof i, 1, f);`